# Are flight tickets and travel insurance required when applying for a Russian tourism visa from China as a foreigner?

Tags: visas, china, russia, tourist-visas

I'm in China and I'm going to applying for a Russian tourism visa. According to the [Russian Embassy in China](http://www.russia.org.cn/en/consular_issues/russian-visa-2/), the following documents are required for the application of tourism via:

> Required documents:
>
> 1. Original passport and copy of the main page (passport should contain minimum 2 empty pages for visas, validity of the passport – 6 months from the end of the requested visa).
> 2. One color photo (3.5 cm x 4.5cm)
> 3. Visa application form (filled on the website https://visa.kdmid.ru).
> 4. Foreign Tourist Tour Confirmation issued by inbound Russian travel agency (original).
>
> **5. Tickets with confirmed dates of entry and exit from Russian Federation.**
>
> **6. Travel insurance valid in Russia.**
>
> 7.Copy of the passport page with a Chinese visa (only for third counties).

At least points 1 to 4 are common to applications in other countries, and I understand 7 is necessary. But I'm not sure if 5 and 6 are required as well.

According to the Russian Embassy in Japan, [flight tickets and travel insurance are NOT required](https://tokyo.mid.ru/web/tokyo-en/tourist-visa), yet [the separate section shows Chinese citizens are required to submit these two additional documents](https://tokyo.mid.ru//en_GB/web/tokyo-en/additional-visa-application-requirements-for-the-citizens-of-third-countries).

> **4. A copy of the insurance policy** (a certificate from the insurance company containing information on the insurance period and the insurance charge) as well as an insurance card containing the information from the certificate, which is valid on the territory of the Russian Federation during the visa validity period, except for cases based on bilateral agreements.
>
> The following countries must follow this requirement: Austria, Belgium, Bulgary, Hungary, Greece, Denmark, Israel, Iran, Ireland, Iceland, Spain, Italy, Cyprus, **China (only for tourist visas)**, Latvia, Lithuania, Luxemburg, Malta, the Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Romania, Slovakia, Slovenia, Germany, Finland, France, the Czech Republic, Sweden, Switzerland, Estonia;
>
> **5. Originals of the travel documents.**
>
> The following countries must follow this requirement: Algeria, Angola, Afghanistan, Bangladesh, Vietnam, Iraq, Iran, **the People's Republic of China**, the Democratic People's Republic of Korea, Nepal, Nigeria, Pakistan, Rwanda, Syria, Somalia, Chad, Sri Lanka and Ethiopia;

I think the *"Originals of the travel documents."* here mean the flight tickets, but I'm not sure.

So my questions:

- Are flight tickets and travel insurance required in the tourism visa application in China, as a foreigner (Japanese)? Or are these documents only required for Chinese but the website doesn't bother to clarify it?
- As to the travel insurance, is there a booth in the immigration gate just like in Belarus, or do I have to prepare it myself?

Answer (score 1):

1. Tickets are your flight documents. You are required to obtain travel insurance for the duration of your stay in Russia and present it with your application for the visa.
2. Because the visa requires details of your travel insurance, you will need to arrange this before you travel.